# How can I use mediaquery in a separate class in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to define dimensions statically in a separate class I can't access contexte.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a initialization function in the class to set the media query  as in the example below

```
class SizeConfig {
 static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
 static double screenWidth;
 static double screenHeight;
 static Orientation orientation;

 void init(BuildContext context) {
   _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
   screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
   screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
   orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
 }
}
```

And call it from your first page like the splash screen page inside the build widget as

```
SizeConfig().init(context);
```

Then call it anywhere as

```
SizeConfig.screenWidth;
```